# Number of elements in the array

Tags: web-services, soa, bpel, oracle-soa

Here is the logic I used in the while loop, the value of i is 1 `$i<=ora:countNodes(bpws:getVariableData('inputVariable','payload','/ns1:Input/ns1:Add'))`.

Here is the xsd I created for reference

```
        <xsd:element name="Add" type="xsd:int" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

When I used countNodes it's throwing an error. Can anyone please explain me where am I going wrong and what function should I use to find total number of elements in the array.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: It says that the process cannot be invoked,while processing the XPath expression; the expression is $i<=ora:countNodes(bpws:getVariableData('inputVariable','payload','/ns1:Input/ns1:Add')). The XPath expression failed to execute; the reason was: Failed to execute countNodes()

Comment: Ok, according to what I understand countNodes can only be used for strings. Using "count" instead solved the problem. @joergl: Thanks, I didn't read the exception in a proper way.

Comment: If that solves your problem, could you post it as answer and accept it? That way, this question will be recorded as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i<=ora:countNodes(bpws:getVariableData('inputVariable','payload','/ns1:Input/ns1:Add'))
```

here instead of countNodes, using count works.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in the BPEL process. Please do it step by step as follow:

1. Use Assign Component for initialize Increment, NodeCount Variables.
      a.Increment Variable initialize it to '1'
      b.Find out the node count of the Array variable using
            ora:countNodes('InputVariable','Payload','element')
2. Use the While-Loop Component with condition Increment Variable< NodeCount Variable
3. At the end of the Loop increment the Increment Variable by '1'

Let me know if you need any thing else..

Comment: Rajesh, Thanks for the reply here I have a question, what is the difference when you say ora:countNodes('InputVariable','Payload','element') and ora:countNodes(bpws:countNodes('InputVariable','Payload','element')).Thanks.